# Part of array as a blank variable

Tags: variable-definitions, list-manipulation, sets

I have a little question.

Let me define the function:

```
f[k_]:=k
```

So 'k' in the argument of 'f' is a blank variable.

Is there a way to define a part of array as a blank variable like:

```
g[x[1]_]:=x[1]
```

Note that `x[1]` is not previously defined.

For example if I write:

```
g[x_[i_]]:=x[i]
```

and if I write `g[x[1]]` the output is

```
x[1]
```

and it is correct.

But if I define

```
h1[x_[i_]?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[y,{y,0,x[i]}]
```

and now I evaluate

```
NIntegrate[h1[x[1]],{x[1],0,1}]
```

I obtain error messages like (I post a figure for a more clear visulization):
[image]

Thanks for any tips and helps.

Comment: This will not work. But could you elaborate a bit more your problem?

Comment: @DanielHuber, I'm going to edit my question and I'll add more details

Comment: @DanielHuber, I edit my answer, this is what I need.

Comment: You have not explained why you want dummy variables, in the function definition or the integral, to be indexed variables.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, observe that dummy variables can be anything, including indexed variables. To be concrete, if you define your h1 using "z":

```
h1[z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[y, {y, 0, z}];
y[k] := k^2;
```

Then for defined y, you can write:

```
NIntegrate[h1[x[i]], {x[i], 0, 1}]
```

and it returns a numerical value. Here the dummy variable "x[i]" in the NIntegrate is playing the role of "z" in the function definition.